# Printing a control

Tags: c#, printing, controls

I was wondering if there is an easy way to print out any control in C# to a printer. My specific example is trying to print a TableLayoutPanel to a receipt (so i don't have to worry about page breaks or anything), but I would like the ability to print out any visible object that is sent to me. Right now I have to create a bitmap, and then do a TableLayoutPanel.DrawToBitmap, but this seems very inefficient and since I already have the Graphics object for printing, there should be an easy way to do this.. Thanks!

Edit: I have noticed that there's a "ControlPaint.Draw__", however it doesn't have a lot of controls it is able to draw (it has Border, Button, CheckBox, ComboBox)..

Comment: You can easily draw it to a bitmap using the DrawToBitmap method. After that, saving the bitmap and printing it is something you can google.

Comment: Like I said, that's what I'm doing now, but there should be an easier/more efficient way to do that. I mean, it shouldn't matter if I'm printing it to a screen or a piece of paper, it should behave the same way...

Comment: There isn't an easy way to draw a control without first using DrawToBitmap.

Comment: This can technically be bypassed with pinvoke, using the WM_PRINT message.  "Seems" is however a very poor motivation to get yourself into that kind of trouble.  The resolution of a printer is drastically higher than the screen.  Something that will give you a headache with pinvoke, but also a reason that "seem" is only seemingly.  Your time is better spent on writing code that draws whatever the control is showing so it doesn't look like a cr*ppy grainy screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static void PrintControl(Control control)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);

    control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height));

    var pd = new PrintDocument();

    pd.PrintPage += (s, e) => e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 100, 100);
    pd.Print();
}
```

It's still using DrawToBitmap, but it's most elegant you're gonna get.

It is pretty concise, readable and not inefficient, so I don't see any reason not to like it.

Comment: Drawing a bitmap isn't terribly efficient, especially if you have to do it a bunch of times and then drawing those to a PrintDocument would make it twice as inefficient (especially when you compare to the speed of drawing a bunch of lines to make rectangles and text). I know that doesn't concern most people, but my target hardware is pretty low-end and it'll be printing a lot of receipts, so that time will add up. I do appreciate the code, though, it is pretty elegant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you use DrawToBitmap, it uses an already rendered "bitmap" of the control, assuming the control is visible in an open form, so I don't think there is much of an overhead. You can, of course, implement control drawing directly to graphics, which will be an awful pain in the ass, and compare performances of the two approaches.

Comment: The controls I'd be printing wouldn't be on a form, I was using them to format a list of items that was being sold. The process of drawing the bitmap onto the PrintDocument is the slowest (in computer time) since it is pretty much going pixel-by-pixel. It also looks pretty terrible if you're trying to draw text at anything other than a large font. I finally settled on just drawing the text myself by evenly spacing the items out. Thanks a lot for the help, though, I can use that if I need to print anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to my own question that's in a somewhat different direction than I was going before. In WPF, you can draw a control to any surface, so I create a "FlowDocument" object and add "Paragraphs" that contain grids, images, and whatever else I need to display. I'll keep the other answer marked as accepted, but I figured I'd add this in case anyone was interested in the direction I ended up going.

```
FlowDocument flowDoc = new FlowDocument();

Paragraph header = new Paragraph();
Grid imageGrid = new Grid();
imageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
ColumnDefinition colDef = new ColumnDefinition();
colDef.Width = new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star);
imageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef);
imageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("{...}", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = bitImage;
image.Margin = new Thickness(10.0d);

Grid.SetColumn(image, 1);
imageGrid.Children.Add(image);

header.Inlines.Add(imageGrid);
header.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

header.Inlines.Add("Some text here");
header.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

flowDoc.Blocks.Add(header);
```

and there should be plenty of examples on how to print out a FlowDocument, but I can always add more to the example if that's needed.