# Print the entire area of the control with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

This is not a duplicat question- the diffenece beetween my question an the others one is my Controler contail a scroller, so they are more informations can't be printed.

I have a C# application that contains a main form name `MainForms`. This `MainForms` has a control `mainDisplay`. I want to print the entire information what we found on the `mainDisplay` to the printer.

The problem is the information on the the control is too big, and I have to scroll to see all information.

Someone have any function that allow me to print this control `MainDisplay` with entire information in it?

This the printscreen of the area of my `MainDisplay` at the right you see the scrollbar:

[image]

I use this Function (Source : [Printing a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418215/printing-a-control))

```
private static void PrintControl(Control control)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);

    control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height));

    var pd = new PrintDocument();

    pd.PrintPage += (s, e) => e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 100, 100);
    pd.Print();
}
```

But my problem still can't print all the informations contain in my control, it's just print a small erea, still need print more informations which are not printed.

Comment: This is not a duplicat question - the diffenece beetween my question an the others one is my Controler contail a scroller, so they are more informations can't be printed.

Comment: Hard to imagine, this comes up over and over again.  There are many problems with printing controls like this, scrolling is the lesser (and nearly impossible) to solve problem.  Much more severe is the drastic difference in resolution between a monitor and a printer.  Every one pixel on the screen gets blown up to a 6x6 blob of ink on paper.  Looks particularly poor for text, the anti-aliasing pixels that make text readable on the low resolution monitor turn into ugly highly visible blobs on paper.  Write a method that takes a Graphics object argument and draws the grid.  Now you can call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the solution. This is the steps i do :

1 - We have a `mainForm`, and this main form contain a control `mainDisplay` with a specific dimension and area, let's say this dimensions is smaller and we get scroll.

2- What i do is i make this `mainDisplay` Empty.

3- i create an other Control `myControlToDisplay`. I draw and i put all fields i want without scroll, so this one `myControlToDisplay` will have a big dimension.

4- on the star-up of my application, i tell to the `mainDisplay` to load `myControlToDisplay`. This time all the content of `myControlToDisplay` will be display on `mainDisplay` with a scroll. Because `mainDisplay` have a small area.

5- I write this functions :

```
Bitmap MemoryImage;
PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
PrintPreviewDialog printDialogPreview = new PrintPreviewDialog();
Control panel = null;

public void Print(Control pnl)
{
    DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
    string datePatt = @"yyyy-M-d_hh-mm-ss tt";

    panel = pnl;
    GetPrintArea(pnl);
    printDialog.AllowSomePages = true;
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Print_Details);
    printDialog.Document = printDoc;
    printDialog.Document.DocumentName = "Document Name";

    //printDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printDoc.Print();
    }
}

public void PrintPreview(Control pnl)
{
    DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
    string datePatt = @"yyyy-M-d_hh-mm-ss tt";

    panel = pnl;
    GetPrintArea(pnl);           
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Print_Details);
    printDialogPreview.Document = printDoc;
    printDialogPreview.Document.DocumentName = "Document Name";

    //printDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (printDialogPreview.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printDoc.Print();
    }
}

private void Print_Details(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    RectangleF marginBounds = e.MarginBounds;

    DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
    string datePatt = @"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
    //String dtString = saveNow.ToString(datePatt);

    // create header and footer
    string header = "Put all information you need to display on the Header";
    string footer = "Print date : " + saveNow.ToString(datePatt);

    Font font = new Font("times new roman", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
    Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // measure them
    SizeF headerSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(header, font);
    SizeF footerSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(footer, font);

    // draw header
    RectangleF headerBounds = new RectangleF(marginBounds.Left-80, marginBounds.Top-80, marginBounds.Width, headerSize.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(header, font, brush, headerBounds);

    // draw footer
    RectangleF footerBounds = new RectangleF(marginBounds.Left-80, marginBounds.Bottom - footerSize.Height+80, marginBounds.Width, footerSize.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(footer, font, brush, footerBounds);

    // dispose objects
    font.Dispose();
    brush.Dispose();
}

public void GetPrintArea(Control pnl)
{
    MemoryImage = new Bitmap(pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height);
    pnl.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height));
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (MemoryImage != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, 0, 0);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
void PrintDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle pageArea = e.PageBounds;
    Rectangle m = e.MarginBounds;

    if ((double)MemoryImage.Width / (double)MemoryImage.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
    {
        m.Height = (int)((double)MemoryImage.Height / (double)MemoryImage.Width * (double)m.Width);
    }
    else
    {
        m.Width = (int)((double)MemoryImage.Width / (double)MemoryImage.Height * (double)m.Height);
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, m);

}
```

6 -And finally we suppose that we have two buttons, one to Print and the other one to print preview.
You just have to call this function :

```
private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Print(mainDisplay.getCurentPanel());
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: \n" + exp.Message);
    }
}

private void PrintPreviewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PrintPreview(mainDisplay.getCurentPanel());
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: \n" + exp.Message);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone :)

good luck